# Docusign template fields not being set

Tags: docusignapi

I've read thru a few SO posts about using the Docusign REST API & populating fields (tabs?), but fields are still not getting populated.

From the Docusign UI, I made a template that has a few roles, including "sender". I uploaded a PDF file that has a few fields. When prompted, I assigned all of them to "sender" role. One of the fields is called "Landlord" (Data Label of this Text field). I POST'd this JSON to the `/envelopes` REST endpoint, but the "Landlord" field/tab doesn't get populated! What's going on? Am I confusing field & tabs? What's missing?

```
{
    'status': 'sent',
    'emailSubject': "Some Document",
    'templateId': 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-4809-a825-1f05a91853e8',
    'accountId': 'XXXXXXX',
    'templateRoles': [{
        'email': 'me@mymail.com',
        'tabs': {
            'textTabs': [{
                'tabLabel': 'Landlord',
                'name': 'Landlord',
                'value': 'John Doe'
            }]
        },
        'name': 'Frank Sinatra',
        'roleName': 'sender'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a quick template with a "Landlord" data field, used your code and my tab populated no problem

```
{
    'status': 'sent',
    'emailSubject': "Some Document",
    'templateId': 'xxxxxxx-6A28-4257-8DAF-1FDDD5920289',
    'templateRoles': [{
        'email': '~testemail~',
        'tabs': {
            'textTabs': [{
                'tabLabel': 'Landlord',
                'name': 'Landlord',
                'value': 'John Doe'
            }]
        },
        'name': 'Frank Sinatra',
        'roleName': 'sender'
    }]
}
```

[image]

Can you confirm there are no trailing spaces at the end of your datafield name?

**EDIT: There were multiple of the same text tab and only the second was populating, for this curious. [This can be resolved by adding "//*" before the tab label.](https://www.docusign.com.au/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Automatically%20Populating%20Tabs.htm)

Comment: There are no trailing spaces in the data field name: [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4caWnxeXmmwX3llSVM2V0oxSHM/view?usp=sharing) I also tried to making tabs in JSON body with no success: 'templateRoles': [{'tabs': {'textTabs': [{'anchorYOffset': '0', 'anchorUnits': 'inches', 'anchorXOffset': '1', 'anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent': 'false', 'anchorString': 'Effective', 'tabLabel': 'Effective Date', 'value': '2016-05-28'}, {'pageNumber': '1', 'yPosition': '100', 'xPosition': '100', 'value': 'should show up', 'documentId': '1'}]}, 'name': 'F S', 'email': 'm@email.com', 'roleName': 'sender'}]

Comment: Wrong image. This one: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4caWnxeXmmwSXQ0WEpvQVB1QzA

Comment: Hi, I don't see an input to change the "Name" [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4caWnxeXmmwd0JQUThqR1NJbDA/view?usp=sharing) . In the "Tool Tip" box, it just says "Text". No way to see the "Name". Please advise. I'm on https://appdemo.docusign.com . Thanks!

Comment: Apologies, I was a bit everywhere. Try displaying initial values to recipients. Click the dropdown in the upper right and "Go to Admin" From there "Sending Settings" and make sure this is checked: http://i.imgur.com/41gyRyd.png

Comment: Apparently, the field was populated further down in the doc & I couldn't see it. Thx @Rickey!